# Одинаковое отображение элементов на экранах с разным разрешением, но одной density

Tags: android, вёрстка

Привет! Только начал работу с Android.
Изучил много инфы по этому вопросу, но остались неясности.
Возможно ли задать верстку в одном layout, чтобы все элементы примерно одинаково (по размерам и расположению) отображались на экранах с разными диагоналями, разрешениями, но одной density?
Т.е. я поместил картинки в соответствующие drawable-*density* папки, создал shape формы, для всех этих элементов задал размеры в dp и помесил все в RelativeLayout. При этом на устройстве xhdpi 1280x768 с диагональю 4,7 и все выглядит как надо. А на xhdpi 2560x1600 с диагональю 10,1 элементы расположены относительно друг друга норм, а относительные размеры меньше требуемых, т.е. Нужно, чтоб на всех экранах интерфейс выглядил одинвково. Вижу,что это использовано во многих приложениях и это должно быть как-то несложно,но нигде не могу найти инфы именно об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать альтернативные ресурсы - создать для планшетов 10" другую разметку (в которой все выглядит , как надо ) с таким же именем , но поместив ее в папку `/res/layout-sw720dp/`
Так же , если потребуются иные ресурсы (/drawable , /values .. ) для обеспечения корректного вида , это тоже решается с помощью квалификаторов .

подробности по поддержке в андроид разных разрешений экрана смотрите [здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Как альтернативный вариант можете попробовать задать различные размеры в dp для разных экранов (dimens.xml) , раскидав их по папкам res/values-*/ с различными квалификаторами , а в layout указывать не абсолютные значения , а ссылку на ресурсы из dimens.xml . Тогда для разных условий , заданных квалификаторами будут различные размеры dp

Задать только в одном layout разметку так , чтобы она выглядела одинаково на всех экранах практически невозможно , но я не вижу причин что то выкраивать - механизм квалификаторов специально создан для решения проблем фрагментации , им надо пользоваться , а не пытаться избегать .

Comment: Ок,спасибо! Да, я читал этот гайд. А нельзя сделать так,чтобы приложение "растягивалось " под большой экран?

Comment: не всегда красиво когда, интерфейс растягивается на весь экран. Но, если вы явно не указали разметку под разные экраны, так и будет происходить.

Comment: pavlofff, не могли бы Вы глянуть и если не трудно ответить на [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82) вопрос ?