# Как нарезать и сверстать макет?

Tags: android, xml, design

Дизайнер нарисовала макет:

[image: Макет]

**Как сверстать такой макет для андроид приложений в целом?**

**С помощью каких компонетов/layout'ов ?**

Черный кружок с 00 - TextView

Ad Free -  кнопка(или ImageView кликабельная)

**Кружок со звездочкой** - кнопка (как вообще ее разместить в этом месте??)

В центре - горизотальные списки с ImageView.

P.S. Про использование 9 png, dp & sp и [поддержку экранов](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) знаю

Comment: Тут слишком много делов, чтобы писать ответ, вот [посмотрите по привязке FAB](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons#embedding-floatingactionbutton-in-header) к заголовку (да и остальное, наверное, не лишним будет почитать)

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо большое за отклик! Больше всего проблем - сверстать header.. остальное более-менее понятно

Answer (score 3):

По поводу **кружка со звездочкой**
это обычная `FloatingActionButton` с установленным свойством `layout_anchor`

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас гляну. Возможно, Вы подскажите как нарезать и сверстать весь header?

Comment: @researcher ну так а с чем еще проблемы то? Вы же написали что знаете про `nine-patch`, эт решает множество вопросов...про `selector`ы знаете?

Comment: про selector'ы не знаю. Сейчас почитаю. А к чему здесь применять nine-patch?

Comment: @researcher ну конкретно в Вашем случае конечно, с обилием кружков nine-patch конечн не особо поможет...shape circle возможно поможет с округлостями

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую сверстать..

Comment: @researcher да так не за что)